# First slash is removed after domain when entering a webpage in the browser

Tags: .htaccess

Sometimes when I hit an address of my webpage in the browser, it removes the first slash after the domain.

Examples:

www.mywebsite.com/scripts/script_6.php  -> trying to load www.mywebsite.comscripts/script_6.php
www.mywebsite.com/test.php -> trying to load www.mywebsite.comtest.php

After entering it again, it loads the page.

A .htaccess settings must be wrong:

```
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/oops.php
ErrorDocument 401 /notallowed.php
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com$1 [R=permanent,L]


DirectoryIndex index6.php

RewriteRule    ^termsofuse/?$    termsofuse.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "adpolicy"
RewriteRule    ^privacy-policy/?$    privacy-policy.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "adpolicy"
RewriteRule    ^newcampaign/?$    newcampaign.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "newcampaign"
RewriteRule    ^howitworks/?$    howitworks3.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "howitworks"
RewriteRule    ^signin/?$    login.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "signin"
RewriteRule    ^reset_password/?$    reset_password.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "register"
RewriteRule    ^error404/?$    oops2.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "register"
RewriteRule    ^error/?$    oops2.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "register"
RewriteRule    ^error401/?$    notallowed.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "register"
RewriteRule    ^notallowed/?$    notallowed.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "register"

#php_flag display_startup_errors on
#php_flag display_errors on
#php_flag html_errors on
#php_flag  log_errors on
#php_value error_log  PHP_errors.log

AddType text/x-component .htc

#ez lehet nem is kell mert gzip van
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

#Enable Browser caching
#<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
Header append Cache-Control "public"
#</FilesMatch>

#Vary: Accept-Encoding header
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


# Enable expirations
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>


#Enable Compression
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>



<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to your `www` enforcing rule. Remember captured string in `RewriteRule` doesn't have leasing `/`.

Replace that with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to test it out in a new browser to avoid browser caching issues.

Comment: Without www it's still wrong. `mywebsite.com/test1.php` becomes `http://www.mywebsite.comtest1.php/`. With www it's fine and it looks like it was always fine. So the problem occurs when I enter the webpage without the www tag

Comment: That is due to your browser cache. Test this in a new browser.

Comment: No it's not. I cleared the cache every time I tried it out. I created a new file (after clearing cache) and entered `mywebsite.com/test2.php`. It has become `http://www.mywebsite.comtest2.php/`

Comment: In that case I suspect you have some code/rule/framework not shown here in your question. Try edited answer.

Comment: I used `%{REQUEST_URI}` in target URL.

Comment: I see that I just don't know how is it different from what I used

Comment: I used `%{REQUEST_URI}` since it's value remains same irrespective of your current directory and `RewriteBase` value.